# Why does SQL query not update specific row

Tags: mysql, sql

Suppose I have this query:

```
UPDATE customerDetails SET age = 17
WHERE customerid = (SELECT max(customerid));
```

Which is meant to change the customer age to 17 for the highest customerid. But, all customer's age change to this value, regardless of ID, why is this?

Comment: do you need to add `from customerDetails` in the subquery?

Comment: I don't see why It would make a difference @Nathan_Sav

Comment: You want the max from the table, so you'll need a FROM clause on that subquery. I'm surprised that your query runs without error written as it is. Mysql is strange like that though.

Comment: When i add FROM customerDetails at the end of the query after taking out ;, it produces an error. Could you please provide an example? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result of:

```
(SELECT max(customerid))
```

is **not** the maximum `customerid` of the table since you did not include a `FROM` clause.
What is odd is that the code runs without any errors and as it seems this SELECT returns the `customerid` of each row!!!
But even if you included the `FROM` clause the code would result in the error:

> Error: ER_UPDATE_TABLE_USED: You can't specify target table
>   'customerDetails ' for update in FROM clause

Mysql allows the subquery only if it is nested inside another one like this:

```
UPDATE customerDetails 
SET age = 17
WHERE customerid = (SELECT t.maxid FROM (SELECT max(customerid) maxid FROM customerDetails) t);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
UPDATE customerDetails 
SET age = 17
ORDER BY customerid DESC 
LIMIT 1
```

What this does is selecting all the data, then order's it by customerid  in descending order(that means the first one will be the one with the largest customerid) and then takes the first result with `LIMIT 1` and makes an update to that row.

[Here is a small DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7201cc71f1b4455ffa3f88d65760bb7f)

One more way to do it is:

```
with cte as(
select max(customerid) as id 
from customerDetails
)
update  customerDetails c
set age = 17 
where c.customerid = (select id from cte);
```

Answer (score 0):

The query doesn't make sense. You are saying `WHERE customerid = (SELECT max(customerid))`
This would get the max id for each row individually. If you want just the max id from the entire table, you need to check the entire table again. You can do this by doing it this way:

```
UPDATE customerDetails SET age = 17
WHERE customerid = (SELECT max(c.customerid) FROM customerDetails c);
```

Comment: This does not work : https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=716e6abb92e52313911d610b45deef2e

Comment: Yes, I was testing with sql server. Do it this way for sql server, otherwise forpas suggestion will work for mysql.

Comment: And my solution will not? :) hehe just kiding, both are correct

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE customerDetails SET age = 17
WHERE customerid = (SELECT max(customerid));
```

What is happening here? The update statement goes through the table row by row and checks whether the row matches the select clause. In the subquery there is no from clause, so you are not selecting from some table there. Instead you access the `customerid` of the row you are currently looking at (it is the only `customerid` that exists in that context). This is one value (one row, one column) and the maximum of that value is the value itself. So, what you have is:

```
UPDATE customerDetails SET age = 17
WHERE customerid = customerid;
```

The condition `customerid = customerid` is true for every row in the table and you update all rows hence.

What you want instead is to update the row the `customerid` of which matches the maximum `customerid` in the table:

```
UPDATE customerDetails SET age = 17
WHERE customerid = (SELECT MAX(customerid) FROM customerDetails);
```

MySQL, however, has problems with accessing the same table that you are updating. So you will have to select from the table one level deeper, which makes this a tad clumsy:

```
UPDATE customerDetails SET age = 17
WHERE customerid = (SELECT MAX(customerid) FROM (SELECT * FROM customerDetails) q);
```

Answer (score -1):

The following should work:

```
create table temp as select max(customerid) max_id from customerDetails;
UPDATE customerDetails SET age = 17
WHERE customerid = (SELECT max_id from temp);
```

Comment: This is not working: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=64375d061e8558faceba3f7820423fd4

Comment: Appears to be an answer that came from the comments with no basis behind it and was rightfully down voted.

Comment: Sorry, didn't have mysql handy to test on.  The update using a temporary table works in the dbfiddle.